# moving a part of a title sligthly above css

Tags: html, css

hope you can help with this:

I have this html:

```css
article {
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url(img/background.jpg);
  height: 20rem;
}

article h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
}

article span {
  color: cadetblue;
  padding-bottom: 0.2rem;
  border-bottom: 0.4rem solid rgb(236, 230, 230);
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h1>Hi, I am <span>web weeb.</span></h1>
  <h2>I'm a Full-stack Web Developer.</h2>
</article>
```

I would need the span to move slightly above the line so it is a bit higher than the rest of the h1, I tried with padding but it moves the border and not the text, also margin is not helping. Any suggestion?

thanks

Comment: `span {display:inline-block; margin-top:-0.2rem;}` experiment with it :)

Comment: Pick your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you need to alter the position of an element, that is, move it some distance from where it would *normally* appear, `position: relative` is your friend.

You can use

```
position: relative;
top: -30px;
```

```css
article {
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url(img/background.jpg);
  height: 20rem;
}

article h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
}

article span {
  color: cadetblue;
  padding-bottom: 0.2rem;
  border-bottom: 0.4rem solid rgb(236, 230, 230);
  position: relative;
  top: -30px;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h1>Hi, I am <span>web weeb.</span></h1>
  <h2>I'm a Full-stack Web Developer.</h2>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **CSS transform** properties for such purposes.

```
article span {
    color: cadetblue;
    padding-bottom: 0.2rem;
    border-bottom: 0.4rem solid rgb(236, 230, 230);

    display: inline-block;
    transform: translateY(-10px);
}
```

First thing, we set span to be displayed as inline-block element so that transform and other properties like width, margin etc can be applied. After that we set transform properties to translateY, which essentially says to move the element along vertical axis. Negative value is provided to move element upward.

Answer (score -1):

Add `position:relative;` and `top:-20;`.

> You can make the inline element as `inline-block` and play around with extra code, so this will lead you to have more and more code(so I rule this out).

Another Option:

> There is already a code here which talks about `relative`, you can refer that well. `relative` will keep the layout in place.

```css
article {
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url(img/background.jpg);
  height: 20rem;
}

article h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
}

span {
  color: cadetblue;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 0.4rem solid rgb(236, 230, 230);
  border: 1px solid red;
  top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h1>Hi, I am <span>web weeb.</span></h1>
  <h2>I'm a Full-stack Web Developer.</h2>
</article>
```

Comment: I would not recommend this, as it makes the span no longer be a part of the `h1` layoutwise. `position: relative` is exactly what you want here. Also, **who are you quoting** in your post?

Comment: @connexo I thought the same.

Comment: Also, since you haven't defined `position: relative`on the `article`, your `top: 10px` refers to the `body` element. Try it out, add `<div style="height: 200px"></div>` before `<article>` in your example. I will add that as a second example in your post so you see.

Comment: No, I got it what you're conveying yes, there should a relative to the parent! so I have removed that code.